# Javsacript object reference from jquery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say that i have this code

```
var SomeClass= function(id){
      this.id = guidGenerator();
      this.htmlElement = jQuery("#"+id);
      this.initClickHandler();
 };

 SomeClass.prototype = {
       initClickHandler: function(){
          this.htmlElement.on("click",function(e){
               //NEED A REFERENCE TO THE OBJECT HERE
               //IN A WAY THAT WILL ALLOW SOMETHING LIKE THIS
               //this.clickHandler();
          });
      },
      clickHandler: function(){
          alert(this.id);
      }
 };

SomeClassInstance1 = new SomeClass("a");
SomeClassInstance2 = new SomeClass("b");
```

how can i get the relevant instance of "SomeClass" on the "ON "callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need a reference to the object here in a way that will allow something like this

Use a variable to keep a reference to `this`:

```
SomeClass.prototype = {
  initClickHandler: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.htmlElement.on("click", function(e) {
      me.clickHandler();
    });
  },
  clickHandler: function() {
    alert(this.id);
  }
};
```

In your case you can also bind the context wbith: [`fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind):

```
this.htmlElement.on("click", this.clickHandler.bind(this));
```

Also note that it's recommended to start instances with lowercase:

```
var someClassInstance1 = new SomeClass("a");
var someClassInstance2 = new SomeClass("b");
```

Comment: @liorr I would recommend you read the post that I marked as a duplicate. It have a lot of good information :-)